# In what situation would くださり（れ）たい△ be plausible Japanese

Tags: grammar, giving-and-receiving

According to this source it's strange but possibly not ungrammatical:

https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9649701.html

But I can't for the life of me think of a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, either.
Might be a typo, as the user says くださる is the polite form of くれる, and くれたい doesn't work just before that part.